# [] operator for strings, link with slices for vectors

Tags: string, vector, rust

Why do you have to walk over the string to find the nᵗʰ letter of a string when you do s[n] where s is a string. (According to https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/strings.html)

From what I understood, a string is an array of chars and a char is an array of 4 bytes or a number of 4 bytes. So is getting the nth letter would be similar as doing this : v[4*n..4*n+4] where v is a vector ?

What is the cost of v[i..j] ?

I would assume that the cost of v[i..j] is j-i and so that the cost of s[n] should be 4.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt for this question to be improved a bit, perhaps rephrasing it from "how does the Rust [] operator work with strings" to "how are Rust strings sliced and how are their characters indexed". There are also a few statements that contradict the given link and would easily attract downvotes.

Comment: @dpc.pw maybe because there are many questions already asked here on SO that explain this if the OP could search a bit harder, or show any amount of the effort that they put in before asking the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:** The second edition of The Rust Programming Language has an improved and smooth explanation to [Strings in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch08-02-strings.html#indexing-into-strings), which you might wish to read as well. The answer below, although still accurate, quotes from the first edition of the book.

---

I will try to clarify these misconceptions about strings in Rust by quoting from the book (https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/strings.html).

> A ‘string’ is a sequence of Unicode scalar values encoded as a stream of UTF-8 bytes. All strings are guaranteed to be a valid encoding of UTF-8 sequences.

With this in mind, plus that UTF-8 code points are variably sized (1 to 4 bytes depending on the character), all strings in Rust, whether they are `&str` or `String`, are not arrays of characters, and can not be treated like such. It is further explained why on Slicing:

> Because strings are valid UTF-8, they do not support indexing:
>
> ```
> let s = "hello";
>
> println!("The first letter of s is {}", s[0]); // ERROR!!!
> ```
>
> Usually, access to a vector with [] is very fast. But, because each character in a UTF-8 encoded string can be multiple bytes, you have to walk over the string to find the nᵗʰ letter of a string. This is a significantly more expensive operation, and we don’t want to be misleading.

Unlike what was mentioned in the question, one cannot do `s[n]`, because although in theory this would allows us to fetch the nth byte in constant time, that byte is not guaranteed to make any sense on its own.

**What is the cost of v[i..j] ?**

The cost of slicing is actually constant, because it is done at byte-level:

> You can get a slice of a string with slicing syntax:
>
> ```
> let dog = "hachiko";
> let hachi = &dog[0..5];
> ```
>
> But note that these are byte offsets, not character offsets. So this will fail at runtime:
>
> ```
> let dog = "忠犬ハチ公";
> let hachi = &dog[0..2];
> ```
>
> with this error:
>
> thread '' panicked at 'index 0 and/or 2 in `忠犬ハチ公` do not lie on
>   character boundary'

Basically, slicing is acceptable and will yield a new view of that string, so no copies are made. However, it should only be used when you are completely sure that the offsets are right in terms of character boundaries.

In order to iterate over each character of a string, you may instead call `chars()`:

```
let c = s.chars().nth(n);
```

Even with that in mind, note that handling Unicode character might not be exactly what you want if you wish to handle character modifiers in UTF-8 (which are scalar values by themselves but should not be treated individually either). Quoting now from the [`str` API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars):

> `fn chars(&self) -> Chars`
>
> Returns an iterator over the chars of a string slice.
>
> As a string slice consists of valid UTF-8, we can iterate through a string slice by char. This method returns such an iterator.
>
> It's important to remember that char represents a Unicode Scalar Value, and may not match your idea of what a 'character' is. Iteration over grapheme clusters may be what you actually want.
>
> Remember, chars may not match your human intuition about characters:
>
> ```
> let y = "y̆";
>
> let mut chars = y.chars();
>
> assert_eq!(Some('y'), chars.next()); // not 'y̆'
> assert_eq!(Some('\u{0306}'), chars.next());
> assert_eq!(None, chars.next());
> ```

The [unicode_segmentation](https://crates.io/crates/unicode-segmentation) crate provides a means to define grapheme cluster boundaries:

```
extern crate unicode_segmentation;

use unicode_segmentation::UnicodeSegmentation;

let s = "a̐éö̲\r\n";
let g = UnicodeSegmentation::graphemes(s, true).collect::<Vec<&str>>();
let b: &[_] = &["a̐", "é", "ö̲", "\r\n"];
assert_eq!(g, b);
```

Comment: Ah ok, I understood: strings cannot be arrays because each letter can be either a c++ char (1 byte) or a Unicode character (4 bytes). So it is a sequence (a linked list ?). str.chars() is also a sequence, but str.bytes() is an array. What if I would like to use a string as an array, can I use UTF-8 arrays ?

Comment: UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding of Unicode codepoints into bytes.  Each codepoint can end up as 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes.  It happens that ASCII characters (as mostly used in English) end up as 1 byte (which is the same value as ASCII).

Comment: A minor nitpick: Unicode scalar values cannot be variable-sized, because they are just numbers, they do not have a defined representation in computers. It's UTF-8 *code points* which are variable-sized, each code point encoding one Unicode scalar value. For example, `char`, being a UTF-32 code point, is fixed-sized, but it still does encode one Unicode scalar value.

Comment: Strange that the docs state: "Iteration over grapheme clusters may be what you actually want" but Rust provides no way to do it. Or is this not actually a common thing to do?

Answer (score 4):

If you do want to treat the string as an array of codepoints (which isn't strictly the same as characters; there are combining marks, emoji with separate skin-tone modifiers, etc.), you can collect it into a `Vec`:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "£10 !";
    for (i,c) in s.char_indices() {
        println!("{} {}", i, c);
    }
    let v: Vec<char> = s.chars().collect();
    println!("v[5] = {}", v[5]);
}
```

[Play link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=160b5b99d66acf017f1da90e90438bc4&version=stable&backtrace=0)

With bonus demonstration of some varying character widths, this outputs:

```
0 £
2 1
3 0
4  
5 
9 !
v[5] = !
```

Comment: Indeed, that is one possibility. I just chose to mention `chars()` because it's lazy and more memory efficient. :)

Comment: Agreed! Sometimes it's useful having O(1) indexing, other times (maybe most times) `chars()` or `char_indices()` are right.

Comment: Thanks. A char is 4 bytes in rust right ? So, if I am using only extended ASCII characters, I can use bytes() to retrieve the table of bytes (and so the table of C++ charcters) ?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "extended ASCII characters".  Only actual ASCII characters (code points 0-127) are one byte in UTF-8.

Comment: ...but I would strongly suggest that you do it properly; it's not that hard!  :-)

Comment: `("v[2] = {}", v[5]);` ? Maybe one of those numbers should be changed?